# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "["0"]"

Tags: android-studio

this is error code:

int countM= Integer.parseInt ( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt ( 
     counterM.trim()  ) ).trim() );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously from the error your counterM.trim() action returns  `“[”0“]”` which is not parsed by `Integer.parseInt(your_invalid_value_here)`

Solution:
Make sure `counterM.trim()` returns String value that can be correctly parsed to Integer.

Comment: Yes you are correct, counterM gives me ["number"],if you know help me to retrive that value,Thank you.

Comment: I changed code now i got this logcat result:java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "["0"]"

Comment: Try using Regex. Use something like 
String parsableString = counterM.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

Comment: Be careful with the String though, the above will remove ANYTHING that is not a number. But your answer definitely lies somewhere in REGEX.